# Reach cloudflare using SSH port forwarding and get error code 1003

Tags: ssh, cloudflare, portforwarding

### Background Info

I'd like to call an api by `https` which is deployed on cloudflare.

But there is a problem on the communcation between local machine and the api provider so I'm doing it with ssh port forwarding
just like:
`<local_server>`-`<remote_server>`-`<target_domain_on_cloudflare>`

I've tried to connected to the `<remote_server>` by SSH and successfully call the API on the `<remote_server>`, so I think the ssh port forwarding gonna work.

### Problem

Here's how I do the port forwarding: `ssh -L 12345:<target_domain>:443  username@<remote_server_ip>`

Here's how I call from local: `curl https://localhost:12345`

And I received the error meesage with **code 1003** from cloudflare saying that:

```
You've requested an IP address that is part of the Cloudflare network. A valid Host header must be supplied to reach the desired website.
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is unrelated to SSH - as the text says, "(a) valid Host header must be supplied", and you're trying to curl `localhost`. You have two ways around this in curl:

1. Use `-H` to specify a host header, and use `-k` to have curl ignore the certificate mismatch:

`curl -kH example.com https://localhost:12345`

(The certificate mismatch will happen because any HTTP headers, including but not limited to `Host:`, are only relevant *after* the TLS session has been successfully established.)

2. Use `--resolve` to bypass DNS and map your real hostname to the localhost address:

`curl --resolve example.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://example.com/`

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've tried the first one, and after I add host header, I got a `403 Forbidden` error, what could be the possible reason? Thanks again!

Comment: 403 means you provided valid credentials but the associated account doesn't have permission to do the requested action.